# Shortcut to avoid checking presence of a hash value twice

Tags: ruby

I have a hash that may or may not contain a value for a certain key. If it does, I want to transform that value and assign the transformed value to an attribute. If not, I want to set the attribute to `nil` (or leave it undefined, which in this case has the same effect).

Is there a more concise / idiomatic alternative to the following code?

```
@my_attr = some_xform(a_hash[:a_key]) if a_hash[:a_key]
```

I feel like there should be DRY alternative that doesn't require mentioning `:a_key` twice (i.e., not `has_key?[:a_key]` either).

(Note that `some_xform()` is a library method that blows up if it gets `nil`, which in most cases is the desired behavior -- I don't want to monkey-patch it to silently return `nil` for `nil` just to handle this case. Nor is there any default value I can pass that will cause it to return `nil`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you apparently don't need to treat `false` specially

```
@my_attr = (v = a_hash[:a_key]) && some_xform(v)
```

Answer (score 2):

Would that work?

```
@my_attr = if (v = a_hash[:a_key]) then some_xform(v) end
```

Comment: That's the best so far.

Comment: In my opinion, it is clearer to write: `v = a_hash[:a_key]; @my_attr = some_xform(v) if v`. Is there an argument for doing it in one line?

Comment: @CarySwoveland From the question statement I got the sense that OP is looking for a one-liner (which is tempting to do in Ruby) with a single hash lookup, that's why I gave that solution.

Comment: I think you should always give what you think is the best solution, regardless of the approach favoured by the OP. Here that could be what the OP wants to avoid, your present answer, what I suggested or something else. When appropriate (including here), explain why you favour your solution.

Comment: Not sure how this is any cleaner or DRYer than OPs original

Comment: It does introduce an extra (repeated) variable, but it's DRYer in that it doesn't repeat `:a_key` or the hash access.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think the one-liner makes the code (in the context of other lines of surrounding code) easier to grasp in a single glance. If I was going to do it in two lines I'd probably want to pull them out into a method to maintain readability at the original assignment site.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this (although not consider best practice by some):

`@my_attr = some_xform(a_hash[:a_key]) rescue nil`

Comment: Interesting idea but it only works if an exception is raised when `some_xform`'s argument is `nil`. We don't know if that's the case.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm assuming that's the case given what was stated: "Note that some_xform() is a library method that blows up if it gets nil"

Comment: This depends _how_ the function blows up. Maybe it takes a long time, or has an ugly sideeffect like locking the database for a while.

Comment: If `nil` was a rare case that might be ok, but it's actually fairly common and not worth the overhead of exception handling every time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the short circuting logic of `&&`:

```
@my_attr = a_hash[:a_key] && some_xform(a_hash[:a_key])
```

If `a_hash[:a_key]` is nil, then `&&` will not evaulate the right hand side, and just return `nil`.

Comment: That doesn't work because there is no default value that I can pass to `some_xform`. What I want is to avoid calling `some_xform` at all, if the key isn't present.

Comment: @DavidMoles I see what you are trying to do now, you can accomplish it with the `&&` operator.

Comment: This is not any less verbose than the original `if` (it just reverses it), and is still not DRY.